# Sending newly created primary key value back to app using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

My mobile app sends a message to SQS which triggers a Lambda function
that inserts data into a SQL DB.
When it creates the new row, it generates a Primary key.  I want to send that
new primary key value to my mobile app before my lambda function is done running.

Should I use SNS to send the value? All opinions appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas come to mind:

1) When you mobile app create the SQS message, it should include some sort of callback information in the payload so that the Lambda knows how to reach back to the mobile app and send the primary key information.

2) This sounds like this should be synchronous REST API call.  Instead of the mobile app creating a message on a queue, could it instead be invoking your lambda function via a synchronous API Gateway request which can then directly return the primary key to the caller.